# Linq to XML grouping with predicates

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

With the below xml, how can I group the following by `str/@itemNo` if and only if `arr[@name = 'ATR_IsFamily'] / str = 1`

```
<root>
  <doc>
    <arr name="ATR_IsFamily">
      <str>0</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_VendorId">
      <str>I23</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="itemNo">ABCDEFGHIJ</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <arr name="ATR_IsFamily">
      <str>1</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="ATR_VendorId">
      <str>I23</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="itemNo">123456789</str>
  </doc>
</root>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var searchResults = from rt in element.Descendants("doc").Descendants("str")
    where (String)rt.Attribute("name") == "itemNo" 
        && rt.Parent.Descendants("arr").ElementAt(1).Value == "1"
    group rt by new { d = (String)rt.Value.Substring(0,6) } into grp
    select grp;
```

This condition is where I am stuck:

```
rt.Parent.Descendants("arr").ElementAt(1).Value == "1"
```

How do I set this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things:

- rt.Parents.Descendants("arr") is going to return you an IEnumerable<XElement> with two items.  By using .ElementAt(1), you'd be selecting the second element, which would be the ATR_VendorId.  You'd want .ElementAt(0).
- Secondly, you're going to want to select the str node beneath that <arr> element, so you'd probably want something like rt.Parents.Descendants("arr").ElementAt(0).Element("str").Value